# Header section for JKExpandTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, jkexpandtableview

I made use of this [library](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView) for expandable table view. Now i need header for sections in my table view which is of JKExpandTableView type. Can anyone help me with this.
Thanx